# 500 internal error installing phpMyAdmin on Mac OS

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I installed **phpMyAdmin** on my Mac and I am getting the following error

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, you@example.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

MySQL works already, I've already installed php applications on my system. These are the steps I took

I downloaded  `phpMyAdmin-4.1.6-english.zip` unzipped it and moved it to  `/usr/local/phpmyadmin416english` changed `config.sample.inc.php` to `config.inc.php` . inside of `config.inc.php` I changed `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']` value to `127.0.0.1`.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

In my `hosts` file I created `phpmyadmin.local` to point to `127.0.0.1`

In my apache `vhost` file I added the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName "phpmyadmin.local"
        ServerAlias "phpmyadmin.local"
        DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/phpmyadmin"
</VirtualHost>
```

I did a HELLO WORLD in the index.php file at the root of `/Library/WebServer/Documents/phpmyadmin` which worked.

I then create a .htaccess file like this..

```
<Directory /usr/local/phpmyadmin416english>
    Options Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

All this is based off of this tutorial http://www.djangoapp.com/blog/2011/07/24/installing-phpmyadmin-on-mac-os-x-lion/

This is what I am getting in the error logs

```
[Thu Jan 30 19:13:07 2014] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] /Library/WebServer/Documents/phpmyadmin/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
```

Comment: You can save yourself a lot of headaches by simply moving the files from `/usr/local/phpmyadmin416english` to `/Library/WebServer/Documens/phpmyadmin`

Comment: yea but I would like to get it to work for the sake of knowing how to do it :) Ive updated my post with information I found in the error logs

Comment: [The *Directory* directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory) is only allowed within the *server config* and *virtual host* contexts

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I am a little slow. This is what I did. I removed the following from the htaccess file. Because I guess the Directory file was not suppose to belong there.

```
<Directory /usr/local/phpmyadmin416english>
    Options Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I then changed this in my vhost file...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName "phpmyadmin.local"
        ServerAlias "phpmyadmin.local"
        DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/phpmyadmin"
</VirtualHost>
```

To this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
        ServerName "phpmyadmin.local"
        ServerAlias "phpmyadmin.local"
        DocumentRoot "/usr/local/phpmyadmin416english"
</VirtualHost>
```

I instead of making the DocumentRoot point to the webroot directory, I just pointed the vhost file there. I would like to know alternative methods if anyone has any.